# How far does buying the Keychain get you in Where's My Water 2?

Tags: wheres-my-water-2

In Where's My Water 2, I've made it to level 30 but there is a locked barrier requiring 3 keys to proceed.

I can supposedly request keys from friends but when I went back and completed the first level it said I was the first of my friends to complete the level, so I'm guessing none of my friends have the game. (Regardless, it doesn't look like the game tells you *which* friends are playing anyway - I don't want to spam my friends who don't have an iPhone, let alone the game.)

As far as I can tell the only other method to progress is to buy a "Keychain". But it's not clear what exactly I get for my purchase. Do I only get the 3 keys for that lock? How much further in the game does that get me, and are there other locks I would need to pay for later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought them, it unlocks the complete beach. On the beach itself are gates too, but these are 'standard duck gates'. Untill now, theres no gate at the very end of the beach, it says 'more coming soon', so a new gate might appear the moment a new place is put into the game, which might be a key gate, or a duck gate

Comment: How many levels are there in the beach part?